# Does the Grand Inquisitor know Darth Vader's true identity?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, star-wars-rebels, order-66

I'm pretty sure this identity of the Grand Inquisitor had been known for some time, though I don't know from where, but the latest episode of Rebels confirm that

> The Grand Inquisitor was a Temple Guard of the Jedi Temple and, as such, was present during the attack led by Anakin Skywalker, now Darth Vader, and the 501st Legion. He surrendered and was turned to the dark side, eventually becoming the Grand Inquisitor.

It seems highly likely that

> surrendered Jedi would have been turned over to Darth Vader, who was not yet constrained to the black suit he later wore. As such, it seems that any surrendered Jedi such as the Grand Inquisitor who eventually survived and joined the Empire under the dark side might have known who Darth Vader really is, even though he would eventually wear a suit. After all, the name is the same as that fallen Jedi who led the attack on the Temple.

So the question:

> Can it be confirmed whether fallen Jedi such as the Grand Inquisitor, who were present at the Jedi Temple during the attack, would know who Darth Vader really is?

Comment: Spoilers!!!!!!!

Comment: lol ok, here goes...

Comment: Where was it confirmed that he was present at the Jedi temple during Order 66 and that he surrendered to Vader?

Answer (score 2):

This is partially addressed by the *Obi-Wan Kenobi* series.

> One of the primary antagonists of the show is an Inquisitor named Reva, who was also present at the attack on the Jedi Temple, and is aware of Darth Vader's identity as a result. She joined the Inquisitors so she could eventually take revenge on Vader.

While the show doesn't explicitly say whether the Grand Inquisitor knew, this at least answers the question of whether other Inquisitors with connections to the Temple knew.